# Non-OR journals which regularly publish OR research

Tags: academia, journals

I am looking for journals which do not focus on OR or a subfield (math programming, simulation, logistics, etc.) but still publish a few OR papers on a regular basis. What are some journals which would fit this criteria?

An example is [Socio-Economic Planning Sciences](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/socio-economic-planning-sciences/vol/67/suppl/C), which isn't explicitly an OR journal, but publishes an article or two every issue which uses OR methods.

Recent papers:

- Faiz, T. I., Noor-E-Alam, M. (2019). [Data center supply chain configuration design: A two-stage decision approach.](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.seps.2018.07.008) *Socio-Economic Planning Sciences.* 66:119-135.
- Caceres, H., Batta, R., He, Q. (2019). [Special need students school bus routing: Consideration for mixed load and heterogeneous fleet.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0038012117301374) *Socio-Economic Planning Sciences.* 65:10-19.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm going to assume here that we are talking about papers utilizing OR concepts (model, solution procedure, some sort of consequences of interest to the readers) as opposed to "pure OR papers" (theorem-proof, metaheuristic races, ...).

1. Many of the journals in supply chain management and related disciplines (operations management, logistics and even sourcing) publish articles that use what I would call OR/MS techniques, concepts or models. In particular, *Naval Research Logistics* publishes some pretty quantitative articles.
2. There are journals in healthcare management (or journals with healthcare departments/areas) that publish OR-type articles. Although I have no first-hand experience, I have been told that *Healthcare Management Science* falls into this category.
3. There are journals in agriculture, forestry etc. that take those types of articles. I coauthored a simulation-based paper in the *Canadian Journal of Forestry* (way back when).
4. On a related note, there are journals devoted to conservation that take OR-type articles. Someone I know is in the review process with an article containing a multiobjective binary optimization model. (I'm not sure I know which journal they are targeting.)
5. Articles containing optimization models can show up in journals in a variety of engineering fields. I've snuck into *IIE Transactions* and *IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence*, and *IEEE Transactions on Networking* may yet get a paper on which I am a contributor.

In many (most?) cases with application-area journals, the journal is mainly interested in meaningful outcomes with reasonable assumptions (and reasonable rigor), and not in how many mathematical symbols you can cram on a page or whether you can prove the problem is NP-annoying.

Comment: "NP-annoying" is that when it's not NP-hard but frustrating enough to deserve its own category?

Comment: It's an "umbrella" term for NP-complete, NP-hard, possibly not even in NP (answers can't be checked in polynomial time) and co-NP-whatever for any defined values of whatever. :-)

Answer (score 8):

### [Theoretical Biology and Medical Modelling](https://tbiomed.biomedcentral.com/)

#### Journal Description

> *Theoretical Biology and Medical Modelling* is an open access peer-reviewed journal adopting a broad definition of "biology" and focusing on theoretical ideas and models associated with developments in biology and medicine. Mathematicians, biologists and clinicians of various specialisms, philosophers and historians of science are all contributing to the emergence of novel concepts in an age of systems biology, bioinformatics and computer modelling. This is the field in which *Theoretical Biology and Medical Modelling* operates.

#### Operations Research Papers

- Polisetty, P. K., Voit, E. O., Gatzke, E. P. (2006). [Identification of metabolic system parameters using global optimization methods.](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1186%2F1742-4682-3-4.pdf) *Theoretical Biology and Medical Modelling.* 3:4.
- Marin-Sanguino, A., Voit, E. O., Gonzalez-Alcon, C., Torres, N. V. (2007). [Optimization of biotechnological systems through geometric
  programming.](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1186%2F1742-4682-4-38.pdf) *Theoretical Biology and Medical Modelling.* 4:38.

Answer (score 7):

Journals focused on electricity/power systems often publish OR papers. Examples include *[IEEE Transactions on Smart Grid](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/RecentIssue.jsp?punumber=5165411)* and *[IEEE Transactions on Sustainable Energy](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/RecentIssue.jsp?punumber=5165391)*.

Answer (score 6):

I would say **[Structural and Multidisciplinary Optimization](https://link.springer.com/journal/158)** with the following description taken from *Springer*.

#### Journal Description

> The journal’s scope ranges from mathematical foundations of the field to algorithm and software development, and from benchmark examples to case studies of practical applications in structural, aerospace, mechanical, civil, chemical, naval and bio-engineering.
>
> Fields such as computer-aided design and manufacturing, uncertainty quantification, artificial intelligence, system identification and modeling, inverse processes, computer simulation, biomechanics, bio-medical applications, nanotechnology, MEMS, optics, chemical processes, computational biology, meta-modeling, DOE and active control of structures are covered when the topic is closely related to the optimization of structures or fluids.
>
> *Structural and Multidisciplinary Optimization* publishes original research papers, review articles, industrial applications, brief notes, educational articles, book reviews, conference diary, forum section, discussions on papers, authors´ replies, obituaries, announcements, and society news.

Answer (score 4):

How about [ACM SIGMETRICS](https://www.sigmetrics.org/)?  Or publications of the [Computer Measurement Group](https://www.cmg.org/)?  Both have lots of work using modeling,  queuing, and simulation.